# Finding limit using polar/non-polar coordinates

Tags: limits, continuity

> Use polar coordinates to find the limit. [If (r, θ) are polar
>   coordinates of the point (x, y) with r ≥ 0, note that r → 0+ as (x, y)
>   → (0, 0).] (If an answer does not exist, enter DNE.)

$$\lim_{(x, y)\rightarrow(0, 0)}\dfrac{3e^{-x^2 - y^2}-3}{x^2+y^2}$$

I used polar coordinates and simplified it down to

$$\lim_{(r)\rightarrow(0+)}\dfrac{3e^{-r^2}-3}{r^2}$$

Where do I go from here?

Also, could someone walk me through the solution without using polar coordinates?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{r\to 0^+}{3e^{-r^2}-3\over r^2}=\lim_{r\to 0^+}{-6re^{-r^2}\over 2r}=\cdots$$
Alternative solution, use that $\lim_{x\to 0}{e^x-1\over x}=1$:
$$\lim_{r\to 0^+}{3e^{-r^2}-3\over r^2}=\lim_{r\to 0^+}3{e^{-r^2}-1\over r^2}=\cdots$$

Comment: How do I know when it is best to use polar coordinates?  Is there anything to look for?  If the question did not say to use it, I would not have known.

Comment: When $x^2+y^2$ appear, obviously. But You can try always, isn't very hard.